# My node.js code in running in VS code but not showing any output in terminal, it is only showing 'code is already running'

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal

[Here is the image of my vs code and the code what I've written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK1Qa.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running your code with an extension and are trying to find the output in the terminal where you did not start the program.

Click on the drop-down menu in the nav-bar above your terminal where it says "powershell" and try switching terminals to see which one shows the output.

Try exploring the different tabs in the nav-bar as well, especially the Output tab.

(This should be a comment but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment)